# How to make a taproot transaction with bitcoin-cli?

Tags: bitcoin-core, testnet, bitcoin-cli, taproot, output-script-descriptors

Can you give a simple step-by-step example for a taproot transaction with bitcoin-cli on Testnet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Steps that I followed to do a transaction which creates a P2TR output:

1. Copy XPUB from test vectors mentioned in [BIP 86](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0086.mediawiki)

```
xpub6BgBgsespWvERF3LHQu6CnqdvfEvtMcQjYrcRzx53QJjSxarj2afYWcLteoGVky7D3UKDP9QyrLprQ3VCECoY49yfdDEHGCtMMj92pReUsQ
```

2. Convert XPUB (mainnet) to TPUB (testnet) using [Bitcoin Extended Public Key Converter](https://jlopp.github.io/xpub-converter/)

```
tpubDC3pD7UZXnsgh3EBjbtBQiB1FnLask7UHBSunZ1DPK4dCFFZoFRkgxHB8gt42FvLzx1DpxfHWxAsYaY6b643RVcGjDxXxns7wKKYnnfEcbB
```

3. Create a blank descriptor wallet with private keys disabled:

```
bitcoin-cli -named createwallet wallet_name=taproot_wallet blank=true disable_private_keys=true descriptors=true
```

4. Save the descriptor info in a text file for TPUB we got from step 2 (descriptor.txt):

```
[
  {
    "desc": "tr([8868ab13/86'/1'/0']tpubDC3pD7UZXnsgh3EBjbtBQiB1FnLask7UHBSunZ1DPK4dCFFZoFRkgxHB8gt42FvLzx1DpxfHWxAsYaY6b643RVcGjDxXxns7wKKYnnfEcbB/0/*)#06sjusfa",
    "timestamp": "now",
    "active": true,
    "internal": false,
    "range": [
      0,
      999
    ],
    "next": 0
  }
]
```

I have copied this format from `listdescriptors` output for a new descriptor wallet that had private keys enabled.

5. Import this descriptor in wallet we created in step 3:

```
bitcoin-cli -rpcwallet=taproot_wallet importdescriptors "$(cat descriptor.txt)"
```

6. This is a watch only wallet with a taproot descriptor TPUB that can be used to create new bech32m address:

```
bitcoin-cli -rpcwallet=taproot_wallet getnewaddress "" "bech32m"
```

```
tb1p5cyxnuxmeuwuvkwfem96lqzszd02n6xdcjrs20cac6yqjjwudpxqp3mvzv
```

7. Send some bitcoin from another wallet:

https://blockstream.info/testnet/tx/2035ead4a9d0c8e2da1184924abc9034d26f2a7093371183ef12891623b235d1

I had compiled bitcoind with branch used by Sjors Provoost in [PR #2260](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/22260)

Comment: But how do you spend from that taproot output? I guess you have to do the same steps while using a privKey instead of a xPub, right?

Comment: Yes use XPRV for mainnet and TPRV for testnet. Test vectors in BIP 86 had no TPRV so I had to follow the steps mentioned in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is the step-by-step example of spending from the  `tb1p8wpt9v4frpf3tkn0srd97pksgsxc5hs52lafxwru9kgeephvs7rqlqt9zj`
Taproot address to the other Taproot one: `tb1p90h6z3p36n9hrzy7580h5l429uwchyg8uc9sz4jwzhdtuhqdl5eqmpwq6n`.

```
$ ./bitcoin-cli.exe -testnet createrawtransaction '[{"txid":"8cdf19ed3ade4af038314ef58b116a523f99aa1c585ca3c157ce5386f9df6421","vout":0}]' '[{"tb1p90h6z3p36n9hrzy7580h5l429uwchyg8uc9sz4jwzhdtuhqdl5eqmpwq6n":0.00001000}]'
$ ./bitcoin-cli.exe -testnet importdescriptors '[ { "desc" : "tr(cV628xvqToz45dwdPmTcJ9RgEVnWMwP8dpZBGzb9LfTk3sBHFNwc)#8skcj28y", "timestamp" : "now" } ]'
$ ./bitcoin-cli.exe -testnet signrawtransactionwithwallet "02000000012164dff98653ce57c1a35c581caa993f526a118bf54e3138f04ade3aed19df8c0000000000fdffffff01e8030000000000002251202befa14431d4cb71889ea1df7a7eaa2f1d8b9107e60b01564e15dabe5c0dfd3200000000" '[{"txid": "8cdf19ed3ade4af038314ef58b116a523f99aa1c585ca3c157ce5386f9df6421", "vout": 0, "scriptPubKey": "5120c38859777bc9c3294d3587035fc3823a146dabaab1fa250bc04e92f16887a065", "amount": 0.00000000}]' "DEFAULT"
$ ./bitcoin-cli.exe -testnet sendrawtransaction 020000000001012164dff98653ce57c1a35c581caa993f526a118bf54e3138f04ade3aed19df8c0000000000fdffffff01e8030000000000002251202befa14431d4cb71889ea1df7a7eaa2f1d8b9107e60b01564e15dabe5c0dfd320140f10fc6bb1d414d4c888838fb6b1699c3e538331d32b64b5baf85c1cc34e2c43eb7bdd7a14fd4a4a07341d1b0390ad977be711bc49df786982243c6564a33f6b400000000
```

Note that the commands with arguments may not work from PowerShell. There is the Bash used in the example above.