# How can I create P2TR addresses with Bitcoin Core 22.0?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, output-script-descriptors, p2tr, bip350-bech32m

I'm trying to test P2TR with Bitcoin Core, and I don't know how to get taproot addresses.
How should I create them using 22.0?

Comment: If you want to experiment with taproot on testnet until it's available in a release: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/108006/how-to-make-a-taproot-transaction-with-bitcoin-cli/

Comment: You can experiment on testnet with existing releases e.g. Core 22.0. It just requires importing a descriptor rather than address generation from within the Core wallet.

Comment: Right, the steps also were tried on Bitcoin Core. I can't edit the comment but until everything is available and easy to do, those steps can be used to experiment with taproot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This functionality in the Bitcoin Core wallet has deliberately [not been merged](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/22364) pre activation to prevent users from easily generating and giving out Taproot addresses prior to the Taproot rules being enforced.

You can get around this by importing a Taproot descriptor into the wallet prior to this PR being merged as described [here](https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/bitcoin-dev/2021-October/019543.html), [here](https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/bitcoin-dev/2021-October/019533.html), [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/107452/how-can-i-spend-from-a-p2tr-address-on-signet-with-the-bitcoin-core-wallet-in-22) or [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/108006/how-to-make-a-taproot-transaction-with-bitcoin-cli/) but that does require you to generate a private, public key pair outside of the Core wallet (or use an existing [test vector](https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/bitcoin-dev/2021-November/019587.html) but don't send to this on mainnet). Unless you know what you are doing I would wait until the Core wallet supports easy generation of Taproot addresses with e.g. the `getnewaddress` RPC for mainnet Taproot address generation.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense!